# Get the UTM tags with Facebook Marketing API

Tags: php, facebook, api, utm

I have few ads on Facebook.

How should I get the UTM tags of this ads through the Facebook Marketing API?

So even nobody open the link with UTM tags, everyday I use Facebook Marketing API to get information about impressions, clicks, source, medium, keyword etc.

What method should I use? Or may I get the target URL with UTM tags from ad statistic? So how can I get the targeted URL (with UTM tags)?

I heard about Ad Report Stats, but there is no instruction anymore about it. This link doesn't work:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/

It redirects to the 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api

Previously thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After so many trials, I could resolve this.

**Case 1:** Need Data from Campaign level to Ad data(Including UTM tags)

We need to get Campaign to Ad level data using [Campaign insights edge.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/) Once we get this we will have ad_id for each row of data. Then loop through each Ad and and pass ad_id to [Ad campaigns edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative#Reading) in order to get UTM params. Field that gives us UTM tags is **url_tags**.

Unfortunately could not find a way around as no where in the marketing API docs there's a way mentioned to join both the edges to get end to end data(Campaign to Ad UTMtags)

Sources : 1) Get campaign to ad level data 2) [Ad level data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative#Reading) (including UTM)

**Case 2** You have ad level data (Ofcourse ad_id)

In this case you have Ad creative edge where you pass ad_id as creative_id. [This source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative#Reading) will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the target URLs from the ad creatives edge for each ad.  See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/adcreatives/) for the documentation, noting in particular the various ad url data types [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/).

My understanding is that the target URL is not available from the Ad Insights edge

Comment: You didn't specify which field in the AdCreative should be, did you?