# How to get Facebook Ads UTM

Tags: facebook

I see that when creating an ad, I can define UTM Tags with the endpoint URL_Tags
=> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/

But if I want to track the performance I am not able to get back the UTM
=> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters

I know that super-metrics are able to get the URL Tags... there is no reason that they can and not the US.
=> https://supermetrics.com/api/getFields?ds=FA&fieldType=dim

If I am reading well, facebook API insight is not able to get me the URL Tags. But is there a workaround? Maybe playing with Facebook ads create the function... a read after write method or something like that?

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: Yes ! you need to fetch utms ad the ad level and not the campaign or the ad set level...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1).The [UTM tags + Facebook](https://marketingland.com/utm-tags-facebook-ads-awesome-209294) ads article explains clearly on Standardizing a UTM protocol

2). For more on Track, FB Ads [refer](http://mixedanalytics.com/blog/facebook-ads-google-analytics-url-dynamic-parameters/) this article

3). Get the UTM tags with Facebook Marketing API [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656082/get-the-utm-tags-with-facebook-marketing-api)

Answer (score 0):

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.adcreative import AdCreative
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi

access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>'
app_id = '<APP_ID>'
id = '<ID>'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
  'name',
]
params = {
}
print AdAccount(id).get_ad_creatives(
  fields=fields

)
```

Just replace your relevant details and add url_tags as a field under fields. You will be able to access all UTM params for every creative under your account.